# $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 + i)|0\rangle$ on the Bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, complex-numbers

By definition, a quantum state can be expressed as
$$|\psi\rangle = a |0\rangle+b |1\rangle.$$
Here, $a, b\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$.

Now, I would like to take $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 + i)$ and $b = 0$. Next, I would like to position it on the Bloch sphere. But the formula for a quantum state for the Bloch spere is 
$$|\psi\rangle = \cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle + e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)|1\rangle.$$
Since $\theta\in[0, \pi]\subset\mathbb{R}$, the values of the $\sin(\theta/2)$ are real too, so I fail to see how we can obtain a complex value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 + i)$ as a coefficient of $|0\rangle$.

Comment: You can multiply the $\psi$ state to any phase $e^{i\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is real. These introduce the same states. In fact, quantum states are from a Hilbert space divided by an equivalence relation defined by this: $a$ and $b$ are in relation if and only if there exists a real number $\alpha$ such that $a=e^{i\alpha} b$.

Comment: So, my state is equivalent to $|0\rangle$ and it sould be depicted as the north pole of the Bloch sphere, right?

Comment: @KNP: Hey, I beleive I got enlightened by your comment. Can you put it as the answer to my question, please?

Comment: South pole cause $\theta=\pi$ is the answer for $\psi=0$. Someone just did it!

Comment: I am sorry, I think an error slipped into my formula, it should be $\cos$ that goes with $|0\rangle$, because $|0\rangle$ is usually depicted at the north pole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum states are rays in the Hilbert space. i.e. $e^{i\alpha}|\psi\rangle$ is the same as $|\psi\rangle$. The set of all $e^{i\alpha}|\psi\rangle$'s with $\alpha\in[0,2\pi)$ is said to form a ray in the Hilbert space. A point on the Bloch sphere represents a ray and not a state.

If you want you can think of the point $(\theta,\phi)$ on the Bloch sphere as representing the set of all vectors $|\psi\rangle = e^{i\alpha}(\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})|0\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})|1\rangle)$.

If you want to understand how we get away working with states instead of rays(i.e. set of states differing by a phase), you can read up on projective representations from Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields Volume I Chapter 3.

Comment: For 1 qubit, the proper geometrical structure  is given by the first Hopf fibration as $S^{3}\rightarrow S^{2}$ with a $S^{1}$ fibre. The Bloch sphere is just the base space and all states on the same fibre are projected to the same base space point.

Comment: Right, agreed. For every point in the Bloch sphere, is a circle. And this indeed gives a three sphere. Thanks for the exact mathematical statement.